# Query spark on JSON object stored on Cassandra DB

Tags: json, apache-spark, cassandra, time-series

I built the structure on cassandra DB to store the time series data of the OS data like services, process and other information. To understand how to works Cassandra about storing JSON data and retrieval the data by CQL queries with condition I prefered to simplify the model. Because in the total model DB I'll have the *TYPE* more complex than report_object like hashMap of array of hashMap for example:
*Type* `NETSTAT--> Object[n] --> {host:192.168.0.23, protocol: TCP ,LocalAddress : 0.0.0.0}`
so the Type NETSTAT will have a list of hashMaps that will contain the fields key -> value. 
For simplify I have choosen to show the following schema:

```
CREATE TYPE report_object (RTIME varchar, RMINORVER int, RUSER varchar, RLANG varchar, RSCRIPT varchar, RMAJORVER int, RHOST varchar, RPATH varchar);
CREATE TABLE test (
REPORTUUID uuid PRIMARY KEY,
report frozen<report_object>);
```

Inside the table I injectioned the JSON data with the followed query inside java class:

```
INSERT INTO test JSON '{"REPORTUUID": "9fb21fb9-333e-4017-ab77-0fa6ee1e20e3" ,"REPORT":{"RTIME":"6/MAR/2016 6:0:0 PM","RMINORVER":0,"RUSER":"Administrator","RLANG":"vbs","RSCRIPT":"Main","RMAJORVER":5,"RHOST":"WIN-SAPV9MUEMNS","RPATH":"C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP"}}';
```

I inectioned other data with the query above.
The questions to clarify my concepts are:
- I would like to do the queries with conditions that check inside TYPE defined, is it possible with CQL or is necessary to use spark SQL?

- Is design DB model right for the purpose (Because I have passed from RDBMS to DB NoSQL) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to query User Defined Type using Cassandra you'll have to create an index first:

```
CREATE INDEX on test.test(report);
```

but it allows only a predicate based on a full document:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE report=fromJson('{"RTIME":"6/MAR/2016 6:0:0 PM","RMINORVER":0,"RUSER":"Administrator","RLANG":"vbs","RSCRIPT":"Main","RMAJORVER":5,"RHOST":"WIN-SAPV9MUEMNS","RPATH":"C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP"}');
```

You'll find more details and explanation in [how to filter cassandra query by a field in user defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33840105/1560062)

When exposed using Spark these values can be filtered using filter on `CassandraTableScanRDD`:

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "test")
rdd.filter(row =>
  row.getUDTValue("report").getString("rscript") == "Main")
```

or `where` / `filter` on a `DataFrame`:

```
df.where($"report.rscript" === "Main")
```

Although query like this using Spark a whole table has to be fetched before data can be filtered. While it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve but it is rather unlikely this will be an useful structure in general.

Comment: Does Scala language is necessary to query the data ? Is it possible with Java language?

Comment: DataFrame API should work out of the box when you replace `===` with equals. `CassandraRDD` will require a custom function, but I don't see any reason why it may not work.

Comment: Could provide me a tutorial or guide to make a test to retrieval data by the query from my structure in Cassandra in Java language ? Thanks