# How to create a materialized view in Cassandra to filter based on part of a user defined type

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types, materialized-views

I have a table with columns (id as primary key, myudt) where myudt is a user defined type. Now I want to do a query based on part of myudt. Based on following discussion it seems one way is to use materialized view but how? Can someone give an example?

[how to filter cassandra query by a field in user defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840105/how-to-filter-cassandra-query-by-a-field-in-user-defined-type/33871326#33871326)

When I try something like below it fails:

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view
  AS SELECT
    myud.fname
  FROM
    source_table
  WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND myudt IS NOT NULL AND myudt.fname IS NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (myudt.fname, id);

The error I get in cqlsh is:

ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 7:28 mismatched input '.' expecting ')' (...NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY (myudt[.]fname...)"

Comment: I don't think that this feature is supported in cassandra. Here is the JIRA for the same https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12463

Comment: The materialized view feature is being 
retroactively classified as experimental, and not recommended for new 
production uses, https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg54073.html. So its better to stay away from them.

Answer (score 0):

The materialized view feature is being retroactively classified as experimental, and not recommended for new production uses, https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg54073.html. So its better to stay away from them.

Searching on a portion of the UDT, defeats the purpose of having them combined in the first place. Design data models based on the queries it has to serve and not vice-versa. Its better to duplicate data by creating another table to serve the queries based on the columns of UDT that you care about.

Comment: not sure it is true. we are using latest version and Materialized Views are very recommended by DataStax team who helps us to integrate Cassandra into our project.