# Cassandra UDT search in a list collection

Tags: cassandra, cql, user-defined-types

I have this structure in Cassandra

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS json_test.sensor_frame (
    id_secret text,
    raw text,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS json_test.json_table (
    user_id text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    device_id text,
    sensor_key text,
    sensor_values list<FROZEN<sensor_frame>>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, device_id), timestamp, sensor_key)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC) AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': '1000'};
```

I would like to search for the value of the field id_secret.

I have been trying with these queries without any success:

```
select sensor_values from json_test.json_table where sensor_values = { id_secret: '703468940' };
select sensor_values from json_test.json_table where sensor_values LIKE {%id_secret: '703468940'%} allow filtering;
select sensor_values from json_test.json_table where sensor_values CONTAINS {id_secret: '703468940'} allow filtering;
```

Is it possible to make the query? Should I change the structure for making this kind of queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to filter cassandra query by a field in user defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840105/how-to-filter-cassandra-query-by-a-field-in-user-defined-type)

Comment: This question is for search in a LIST of UDTs, not for search in a UDT field. The same solution does not apply