# Is there is a way to select or filter the list of UDT in Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

From the below select response. How can i add where clause to filter the flights between the requested arrival time.

```
cqlsh:api_itl> select * from generic_response_1;

 trace-id                             | result-index | api | base_price | fare_selection | fare_type | flights                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | sale_price | special_instructions | total_duration
--------------------------------------+--------------+-----+------------+----------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------+----------------
 39485363-cc22-4eff-a502-6d860931c3fb |         IB56 | tbo |       8400 |         Retail |       ADT | [{arrival_date_time: '23-03-2019 14:10', carrier_iata: 'UK', carrier_id: 'UK 816', carrier_name: 'Air Vistara', class_code: 'Q', departure_date_time: '23-03-2019 11:30', flight_duration: 160, field_7_: 'BLR', to: 'DEL', via: ''}, {arrival_date_time: '23-03-2019 22:40', carrier_iata: 'UK', carrier_id: 'UK 835', carrier_name: 'Air Vistara', class_code: 'Q', departure_date_time: '23-03-2019 19:55', flight_duration: 165, field_7_: 'DEL', to: 'MAA', via: ''}] |       9485 |                 null |            670
 39485363-cc22-4eff-a502-6d860931c3fb |          OB4 | tbo |       1000 |         Retail |       ADT |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [{arrival_date_time: '08-03-2019 14:55', carrier_iata: '6E', carrier_id: '6E 119', carrier_name: 'Indigo', class_code: 'Q', departure_date_time: '08-03-2019 13:55', flight_duration: 60, field_7_: 'MAA', to: 'BLR', via: ''}] |       1770 |                 null |             60

(2 rows)
cqlsh:api_itl>
```

Database structure for the given output

```
CREATE TYPE api_itl.flight (
    arrival_date_time text,
    carrier_iata text,
    carrier_id text,
    carrier_name text,
    class_code text,
    departure_date_time text,
    flight_duration int,
    "from" text,
    "to" text,
    via text
);


CREATE TABLE api_itl.generic_response_1(
    "trace-id" uuid,
    "result-index" text,
    api text,
    base_price float,
    fare_selection text,
    fare_type text,
    flights list<frozen<flight>>,
    sale_price float,
    special_instructions list<text>,
    total_duration int,
    PRIMARY KEY ("trace-id", "result-index")
)
```

Comment: change your data model to have clustering keys by arrival time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to filter cassandra query by a field in user defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840105/how-to-filter-cassandra-query-by-a-field-in-user-defined-type)

Comment: @ChrisLohfink How to model? If my model is wrong, suggest me how to structure it?

Comment: @picadoh What u have suggested is dictionary, In my case the column flight is a list. Could you suggest me How to create like suggested UDT. Because My Udt is list of UDT

Answer (score 0):

Data which is part of TYPE can't be filtered using CQL. Instead, consider changing the data model.

First, make TYPE to a TABLE.

- Consider changing datatype of arrival_date_time to timestamp.
- Also, add trace-id, result-index to maintain a reference to the main table.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE api_itl.flight (
>     arrival_date_time timestamp,
>     carrier_iata text,
>     carrier_id text,
>     carrier_name text,
>     class_code text,
>     departure_date_time text,
>     flight_duration int,
>     "from" text,
>     "to" text,
>     via text,
>     "trace-id" uuid,
>     "result-index" text,
>     PRIMARY KEY ("carrier_id", "arrival_date_time") );
> ```

Next, remove flights `list<frozen<flight>>` from original table.

Now you could use **two** queries to get your desired result.